# AWS HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tomcat8

I am trying to host my spring mvc application on aws. I am very new to aws and somehow I managed to deploy it on aws ec2 instance but now I am getting a **HTTP Status 404 – Not Found. The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.** I used **tomcat 8.5.64** on my local machine while building the application and on aws I have **tomcat 8** installed.
So i want to know that is tomcat server version creating a problem or something else. And if it is creating the problem how can i change the tomcat server version on aws or how can I redeploy my application on aws if I change the tomcat server on my localhost.

**Edit:** **All the ports running on linux server**

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q    Local Address      Foreign Address    State
tcp        0           0 0.0.0.0:22           0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN
tcp        0         0 127.0.0.1:3306         0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN
tcp        0          0 127.0.0.53:53         0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN
tcp6       0             0 :::22                :::*         LISTEN
tcp6       0          0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*         LISTEN
tcp6       0             0 :::8080              :::*         LISTEN
udp        0          0 127.0.0.53:53         0.0.0.0:*
udp        0          0 172.31.4.19:68        0.0.0.0:*
```

**tomcat 8 server log**

```
23-Jun-2021 09:46:33.282 INFO [Thread-3] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
23-Jun-2021 09:46:33.326 INFO [Thread-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
23-Jun-2021 09:46:33.438 INFO [Thread-3] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
23-Jun-2021 09:46:33.449 INFO [Thread-3] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
23-Jun-2021 09:48:10.681 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:10.716 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:10.716 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:10.717 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:10.743 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:10.743 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:10.743 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:10.761 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:10.761 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:10.761 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:10.761 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:10.761 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.616 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.39 (Ubuntu)
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.616 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 9 2019 19:47:51 UTC
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.616 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.39.0
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.616 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.616 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.4.0-1049-aws
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Ubuntu
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /var/lib/tomcat8
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat8
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.619 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.619 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.619 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat8
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.619 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.619 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat8-tomcat8-tmp
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.619 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.21] using APR version [1.6.3].
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.619 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.643 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.820 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.865 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
23-Jun-2021 09:48:15.912 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 4411 ms
23-Jun-2021 09:48:16.190 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:16.191 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.39 (Ubuntu)
23-Jun-2021 09:48:16.288 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/FOODHUB.war]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:24.090 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
23-Jun-2021 09:48:24.244 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/FOODHUB.war] has finished in [7,950] ms
23-Jun-2021 09:48:24.245 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:25.896 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
23-Jun-2021 09:48:25.905 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [1,661] ms
23-Jun-2021 09:48:25.929 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
23-Jun-2021 09:48:26.008 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 10095 ms
```

Comment: is ec2 instance a linux os or windows server?

Comment: what is tomcat server running?

Comment: @Ali ec2 instance is linux (ubuntu) server

Comment: @jatinMehrotra yes it is running

Comment: Can you attach all the port running on Linux ?

Comment: @Ali you can just check all the running ports above in post

Comment: Check Tomcat's logs: `/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.<today's date>.log`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz please check the server logs in post above

Comment: You application should be available under `http://example.com:8080/FOODHUB/`, where `example.com` is the domain name or IP address of your server.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz yes! but when I am accessing this link I am getting 404 error. Please guide me to what should I do now to make it work.